# Automatically open Content Assist in Eclipse when removing wrongly typed letters

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist, keystrokes

Is there a way to open Java Content Assist in Eclipse, when pressing backspace (i.e. removing wrongly typed letter)?

Consider an example: When we type `this.`, the Eclipse opens Content Assist windows with code completion suggestions. Then if we write a text, that is not suggested (e.g. it suggests a series of `get*` methods, and we type `this.gw`), the Content Assist window disappears. Then when we press backspace to remove wrongly typed letter, the assist window remains closed.

Is there a way to automatically reopen this window? Is there a setting in preferences for this?

I know that `ctrl+space` brings back Content Assist window, but that's not a solution. I just want more friendly behavior of IDE, known from e.g. Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

How about pressing `Ctrl+z` instead of backspace? IIRC that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

By default, content assist is automatically activated by '.'. To get around this issue, you could either delete all the way down to '.' and retype the period or change the way eclipse activates content assist.

You can do this by changing the **'Auto activation triggers for Java'** setting under **Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist** from '.' to all the letters of the alphabet. This would take care of the issue but might introduce other unwanted behavior.